# React Native - CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBReactNativeSpec"

Tags: react-native

The react native version has been updated from 0.61.5 to 0.65.0.

After `pod install` I receive an error stating,

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBReactNativeSpec":
  In Podfile:
    FBReactNativeSpec (from `../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec`)

Specs satisfying the `FBReactNativeSpec (from `../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

The path for FBReactNativeSpec in Podfile is,

```
pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
```

I cannot figure out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6):

try updating the platform version in your podfile.

`platform :ios, '11.0' => change 11 to 15.`

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This could be an error with dependency, you may need to install **react-native-codegen** library like:

If you're using `yarn` packager:

```js
yarn add --dev react-native-codegen
```

If you're using `npm` packager:

```js
npm install react-native-codegen --force
```

And it will add the library in `package.json`

```js
"dependencies": {
   "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7"
}
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31180) out for more info.

Also, I'll recommend you to follow [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.60.5&to=0.65.1) document for `Package.json` and `Podfile` changes.

Comment: 'react-native-codegen' did not work in my case.
I installed it as devDependency using npm and yarn, tried putting it as resolution, deleting node_modules at every step and often package-lock, but I am receiving the same error.

If any other info is required, I will update it in the question.

Comment: try to remove `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder & clean build folder. Next, do `pod install` then open your `.xcworkspace` project and build again. Also, React Native Upgrade Helper document may help you with `Podfile` changes.

Comment: Updating the Podfile worked. Thank you.