# ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

note: Removed stale file '/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-dnufrguwrmgikugjqxtulxmaanbo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-12214CBC4BD7A3B768E202B6C61A3E87.sh'

note: Removed stale file '/Users/manu-vs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-dnufrguwrmgikugjqxtulxmaanbo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-config.build/Script-3B02E6DD8C05F63F0A87FAD657BC47C3.sh'

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cigar-dnufrguwrmgikugjqxtulxmaanbo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/proj.app/proj normal (in target 'proj' from project 'proj')
(1 failure)

REACT NATIVE version 0.65.1

COCOAPODS version 1.11.2

Comment: Did you upgraded your react-native version that's because you're facing it?

Comment: yes, i upgraded from 0.63.3 to 0.65.1

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident with your code then clean `build` folder & close your project file, next remove the `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder. Next, do `pod install` then open your `.xcworkspace` project and build again.

If you still face the issue then try my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374290/react-native-cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-fbreactnati/69374533#69374533).

Hope this works for you.